# Python beginner OOP functions

Tags: python

Can you help me to solve the problem, why am I not able to call my functions? I try to calculate the average mark of all student objects created but it somehow doesnt work.

```
class Student:
    anz = 0

    def __init__(self, vorname, nachname, studetnId, averageMark):
        self.vorname = vorname
        self.nachname = nachname
        self.studentId = studetnId
        self.averageMark = averageMark
        Student.anz += 1

    def totalAverageMark(self, input):
        summe = 0
        for s in input:
            summe += self.averageMark
        return (summe / Student.anz)

    def getName(self, arr):
        for s in arr:
            return self.nachname

students = [Student("Maxine", "Muster", 2, 1.0), Student("Bert", "Beispiel", 1, 2.0)]

print(students.getName())
print(students.totalAverageMark())
```

It says: AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'totalAverageMark'

Comment: Somehow? How exactly? Always include error messages and explain how your code is failing so we don't have to guess or work it out. Do you know how to use lists (such as `students`) in Python?

Comment: `students` is a *list*. As the error tells you, `list` objects do not have those methods

Comment: There is one conceptional error as well: You can ask a `Student` for their name (`getName()`), but asking one about the total average mark (`totalAverageMark()`) you can't expect them to return any info that includes other students. BTW: What is the meaning of the parameter to `getName()`? It doesn't make sense. You'd see that yourself if you made a human language description of what each method does, including the paramers.

Comment: would like to suggest not to use keywords like ```input``` as a parameter name in ```def totalAverageMark(self, input):```.

Comment: @Ulrich Eckhardt Ok, got that! So that is why I need to create a new class or just some code outside the functions right?

Comment: Yes. This simply doesn't belong into the student class. As a general rule, don't put things into a class unless the class needs it. BTW, your homework has very little to do with OOP: The student class is a mere aggregation of data without own behaviour, there is no derivation nor are any interfaces implemented.

Answer (score 2):

`Student` define attributes of a single student only single. to get the collective result for example avg mark of all student, you need to create a class (that bind all students say) that defines the attribute of the class ie there students.

below is a simple implementation what you are trying to do using OOPs

```
class Student:
    def __init__(self, vorname, nachname, studetnId, averageMark):
        self.vorname = vorname
        self.nachname = nachname
        self.studentId = studetnId
        self.averageMark = averageMark
class Students:
    def __init__(self, students_list: list):
          self.students = students_list
    def avg_marks(self):
        total_students = len(self.students)
        marks = sum(student.averageMark for student in self.students)
        return marks/total_students

students = [Student("Maxine", "Muster", 2, 1.0), Student("Bert", "Beispiel", 1, 2.0)]
student_data = Students(students)


print(student_data.avg_marks())
```

Comment: Wow, thanks a lot. I believe I can figure out what you mean.

Answer (score 1):

`students` is a list of your students. List has not functions `getName` and `totalAverageMark`. You can use them only with object of `Student` class.

Simplest way to get total average mark of students:

```py
class Student:
    anz = 0

    def __init__(self, vorname, nachname, studetnId, averageMark):
        self.vorname = vorname
        self.nachname = nachname
        self.studentId = studetnId
        self.averageMark = averageMark
        Student.anz += 1

students = [Student("Maxine", "Muster", 2, 1.0), Student("Bert", "Beispiel", 1, 2.0)]

sum = 0
for s in students:
    sum += s.averageMark
print(f"Total average mark is {sum / len(students)}")
```

Comment: I think it would help to expand your answer to show how to call these methods against one or more students.

Comment: Well exactly, I understand what @Ratery means. But how am I able to iterate through the list, and therefore get the total Average mark?

Comment: @MartinMüller what do you mean? Are you asking how to iterate over a list? This really has nothing to do with your stated question.

Comment: @MartinMüller I have edited my answer. You don't need class methods to do it.

Comment: So it should also be possible to write that in a method, right?

Comment: Yes, but I think it is not necessary. But you can make usual function, not method. Or use `@classmethod` decorator.

Comment: ```
    def Average(self, liste):
        sum = 0
        for s in liste:
            sum += s.averageMark
        print(f"Total average mark is {sum / len(students)}")

students.Average()
```

Comment: Sorry thats hard to read but I want to understand the system behind. When I try to implement it as a function it doesnt work

Comment: Use `Average(students)` instead of `students.Average()`.

Answer (score 0):

To iterate through the list and print out the result for each `student` you can use the following:

```
for student in students:
   print(student.getName())
   print(student.totalAverageMark())
```

Or to access an individual student

```
students[0].getName()
```

Comment: Yes, but no: This won't run. Also, it won't give the average mark of all students.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to call the methods `getName()` and `totalAverageMark()` directly on the students list object instead of accessing each individual `Student` objects within the list.

Iterate over each `Student` object in the `students` list and call the methods on each object:

```
class Student:
    anz = 0

    def __init__(self, vorname, nachname, studentId, averageMark):
        self.vorname = vorname
        self.nachname = nachname
        self.studentId = studentId
        self.averageMark = averageMark
        Student.anz += 1

    @staticmethod
    def totalAverageMark(students):
        summe = 0
        for student in students:
            summe += student.averageMark
        return summe / len(students)

    def getName(self):
        return self.nachname

students = [Student("Maxine", "Muster", 2, 1.0), Student("Bert", "Beispiel", 1, 2.0)]

average_mark = Student.totalAverageMark(students)
print(f"Average Mark: {average_mark}")

for student in students:
    name = student.getName()
    print(f"Student Name: {name}")
```